# CSS Fonts Do Not Work With jQuery On Click

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile, fonts

So I was about to release a free plugin today and I ran into a huge issue, none of the icon buttons work on mobile devices and I can't figure out a good solution to this without having to bucher the layout and use images for the icons.

Basically it seems like icon fonts, or imported CSS fonts do not work with click detection on mobile devices ( I tried the fiddle on an iPhone 4, iPhone 5, and iPad 3 all iOS 6.x ) and not one of them registered the click.

I have also tried using touch etc. within the on command to no avail. Can anyone shed some light on this?

JSFiddle - http://goo.gl/pQxce

Comment: Did you notice if tapping twice counted as a click?  I've noticed on iOS devices, sometimes the first tap is registered as a hover, and the second one (after a pause) is the click event.  Just an idea.

Comment: This is not ideal, especially if you are using toggle switches, filters, buttons, etc. Most users will just assume it's broken. I think I may have found a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs across this annoying issue when using icon fonts, css fonts, etc. then hopefully this will help. If you can't get the click to register (first time) I found the solution was as easy as adding padding to the element.

I tried a lot of different things (much more complicated) before stumbling on this, but it seems with a simple 1px padding the button works perfect on mobile devices.

http://goo.gl/XZzsL - Updated Fiddle Example

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that ios "thinks" there is nothing in the anchor tag, so you cannot touch/click the icon. Adding padding to the link did not work for me, but adding a display:inline-block and giving it a set width worked for me.

```
.close-button{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    width:10px;
}
```

Check out the modified jsfiddle which works: http://jsfiddle.net/pA9pH/9/